# animation in cocos2d

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing a game using the engine cocos2d. How to use this engine to create an animation similar Fireball (when the flaming fireball bounce off the screen and leave a trail of smoke behind it.) ?

Answer (score 1):

try using a particle emitter like the one at http://particledesigner.71squared.com/